# How to extract a specific mysql database table field only when a particular database operation is carried out in debezium kafka connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

So i want to extract the value of email field from mysql database user's table only when an INSERT operation happens.

See my configuration so far:

```
{
  "name": "smartdevnewuserconnector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",  
    "database.hostname": "mysql",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.password": "*PASSWORD*",
    "database.server.id": "184055",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",  
    "database.server.name": "smartdevdbserver1",  
    "database.include.list": "smartdev_db",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.smartdev_db",
    "table.whitelist": "smartdev_db.users",
    "column.blacklist": "smartdev_db.users.id,smartdev_db.users.password, smartdev_db.users.fullName, smartdev_db.users.address, smartdev_db.users.phoneNo, smartdev_db.users.gender, smartdev_db.users.userRole, smartdev_db.users.User_status, smartdev_db.users.reason_for_inactive, smartdev_db.users.firstvisit, smartdev_db.users.last_changed_PW, smartdev_db.users.regDate",
    "transforms": "unwrap, copyEmailValue",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.copyEmailValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.copyEmailValue.field": "email"
  }
}
```

I have succeeded in extracting the email value but don't know how to go about the part b - which is extract the value of email only for an INSERT operation.

See what i tried:

```
{
  "name": "smartdevnewuserconnector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",  
    "database.hostname": "mysql",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.password": "*PASSWORD*",
    "database.server.id": "184055",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",  
    "database.server.name": "smartdevdbserver1",  
    "database.include.list": "smartdev_db",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.smartdev_db",
    "table.whitelist": "smartdev_db.users",
    "column.blacklist": "smartdev_db.users.id,smartdev_db.users.password, smartdev_db.users.fullName, smartdev_db.users.address, smartdev_db.users.phoneNo, smartdev_db.users.gender, smartdev_db.users.userRole, smartdev_db.users.User_status, smartdev_db.users.reason_for_inactive, smartdev_db.users.firstvisit, smartdev_db.users.last_changed_PW, smartdev_db.users.regDate",
    "transforms": "unwrap, copyEmailValue, filter",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.copyEmailValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.copyEmailValue.field": "email",
    "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
    "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
    "transforms.filter.condition": "value.op == 'c'"
  }
}
```

After doing this, i got the error: op is not a property of value; then i realized that ought to be true because i am overwriting the original content of value with the extracted email value.

Please can someone guide me on how to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter transform needs to be listed before you remove the op field with the unwrap transform

Try

```
"transforms": "filter,unwrap,copyEmailValue",
```